# JBoss AS 4.2.2 migration/upgrade

Tags: jboss, migration, upgrade

I have to migrate from JBoss AS 4.2.2 to a newer version and maintain support for several legacy apps already productive.

One requirement I've is: "don't touch any working/productive code!"

My question is:

Which version of the AS is the best to achieve this goal? Which is the most "smooth" to do the transition?

Answer (score 2):

That's a loaded question. A lot of it depends on what the application is using (EJB, JMS, JSP etc...).

Lets take a few scenarios

Simple App (.war) with just bunch of JSP's and basic configuration (datasources, application web context, ports etc...). If this is the case, you can migrate to pretty much any version with relative ease. Does not need any code changes. Only configuration changes.

Moderately complex app (.ear), has a few EJB's, JSP and JMS. This will probably need some re-writing irrespective of which version you migrate to. JBoss 5 support EJB 2.1 so migrating to JBoss 5 probably more easier than JBoss AS 7.

Complex App (.ear, .sar and more) which actually uses JBoss specific interfaces (JMX, .sar, .rar) and does extend (like for authentication using custom authentication modules etc...). This will need migration of that custom mode to which ever version you are migrating to. You still have to do what you do for the "Moderately complex app".

Comment: Good point. I forgot to tell. It's a WAR and several JARS packed within an EAR. No EJB's or JMX use. Lots of JSP's, Servlets and Axis2 web services deployed with the web app (as servlet). Uses struts, log4j, apache commons & quartz scheduler.

Comment: If you have no EJB's, is there a reason you are using the EAR packaging?

In any case, I think based on you description you'll probably be able to migrate to any version you like with similar effort. I'd recommend the latest obviously because going forward the architecture of JBoss will be based on AS 7.

Comment: The EAR exists because Axis2 has it's own war and they're packaged together. I've read that AS 7 has a very different classloading system right? This could be an issue?

Comment: AS 7 classloading is quite different, that right. They are designed as Modules (each library can be a module with one or more jar files) and applications have to specify explicit dependencies on these modules. But that is relatively straightfoward compared to other migration aspects like code re-rewrites etc...

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! (and sorry for my english)